# Entity Framework - Disposed ObjectContext not collected by garbage

Tags: entity-framework-4, memory-leaks

As the title suggests, i recently discovered when i was trying to track down potential memory leak issues, that a disposed objectcontext doesn't seem to be garbage collected. I'm using EF 4 in a WPF application alongside Prism and MVVM. And when i started to look around for solutions I bumped into this post:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666304/memory-leakage-issue-in-entity-framework

All my objectcontexts are per transaction used inside a using block. I was assuming all along that the objectcontext would be disposed and eventually be collected by the GC. Apparently only the first part of it has been happening (I'm using memprofiler). Can someone point me to a resource or let me know of a way to have GC collect the disposed objectcontexts.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage collection and Dispose are two different aspects of memory management.

Dispose is a method on your class where you can release resources manually.

Garbage collection only happens when the .NET garbage collection engine decides to run. It's generally recommended that you not try to tinker with this process. The garbage collector will only run when some heuristic tells it that you're running low on memory, which on today's hardware may be never (especially if you're on a 64 bit machine).

If you want to play with forcing collection to happen you can use:

```
GC.Collect();
```

Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx

Comment: I understand the differences. Thanks for pointing that anyway. Definitely answers the question of how to force GC to run to collect disposed objectcontext. But essentially i'm trying to understand if this is what happens with EF in all enterprise apps and how are managing memory in their apps. Probably I should have phrased the question like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this sequence of calls useful in forcing GC to run.

```
GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

try
{
    Process curProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    curProc.MaxWorkingSet = curProc.MaxWorkingSet;
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

However, in reading the Microsoft Connect article you linked, GC not running is not the problem of that user. What that user was doing is sticking an entity class in `Session`, which is a terrible move and will prevent the parent class from getting disposed for the reasons outlined in the answer (change tracking).

The session stored object should be a disconnected class not what you retrieve from the context. As long as you're not doing that, your object context will get disposed when the last reference to anything you retrieved from it is released.

Comment: How exactly does my answer confuse GC and Dispose? I was answering the part of his question about getting the GC to fire. The answer above me already clarified the difference between GC and Dispose, so I didn't feel the need to repeat the explanation.

Comment: Primarily your last sentence, where you mention that a 'reference' being held is preventing something from being disposed. This terminology is generally used in the context of saying that a 'reference' to an object instance will prevent GC. Saying that a reference to something is preventing it from being disposed seems odd, because you actually need a reference to call `Dispose` in the first place (aside from when it's being called in a finalizer). However, reading more closely, I'm not sure your answer was confused about that, after all. But a subsequent reader might be.